# @autowired for JwtBuilder class is not working, error: required a bean of type 'io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, jjwt

I am trying to autowire the JJWT JwtBuilder which is imported from this package  io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder , however I am getting an error as shown below (at the end of the question)

I have fixed a similar error when autowiring my own class **by using a @service annotation in the beginning of my imported library**, however since this is a standard library I can't add @service annotation to it

I am calling the library like this in my impl file:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder;
....
@Autowired
JwtBuilder jwtBuilder;
```

The dependency in gradle is

```
compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'
```

The error:

```
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jwtBuilder in ....CustomerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that you create the instance of `JwtBuilder` using the static `builder()` method of `Jwts` class.

```
JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
```

You can refer [following documentation](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt).

Comment: Thanks a million, it worked as you advised, how can I know when I should use a static builder instead of @ Autowired ? is there any clue to conclude that ? I tried searching about it but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: Usually, builders follow what we call a Builder design pattern and are expected to be used as a non singleton objects. Moreover, API references are the best place to look at to find clues about weather how to instantiate the object

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am still a beginner in Spring boot so I wasn't very sure about what happened, also I didn't find a guide for how to use this class which confused me more, can you pass a link for the API references you meant as I didn't find them ?

Comment: Edited the answer to include the link to the documentation for JJWT

Comment: sorry it seems I mixed up what I read in multiple pages, now it is clear, thanks